# how to read in from a file using scanner and display in a different order

Tags: java

I have a file that contains numbers separated by a space, i can read in the file using scanner, and it displays just as the file shows it. How can i print the numbers vertically one by one?

```
try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)){
            while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                String line = reader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Comment: current output 1 3 4 5 6 , desired output its the same but vertically. and adding an extra space between 1 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the resulting string from `reader.nextLine()` into an array.

```
try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)){
        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            //split line into an array, delimited by spaces
            String[] lines = line.split(" ");
            //loop through the resulting array
            for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++){
                //print each number on a single line
                System.out.println(lines[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operation `split()` on strings:
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

```
String s = 1 2 3 4;
String[] result = s.split(" "); // this will split on space
```

Afterwards you can simply go through the array with a `for`-loop and print each value:

```
for(String str : result) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Tipp: You can even limit the size of your array: `string.split(" ", maxArraySize);` will give you a `String[]` of length `maxArraySize` or shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Split the line into a `String[]` by spaces and then iterate over the array printing each item on a new line.

```
String[] lines = line.split(" ");
for (String item : lines) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to split the `String` by the delimiter `" "` then simply iterate over those elements.

```
String line = reader.nextLine();
Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).forEach(System.out::println);
```